# superset dashboard table type when query large data crush and be slow?

Tags: python, olap, apache-superset

Now I used superset dashboard(table) to query detail data, however when query result more then 50K rows, because of large data render in the browser, It will make web browser crush and be slow, I think if there any solution to solve that problem.

Cases: I used superset dashboard as detail data query, however data rows return more than 50K rows to the browser, It will cause browser crush and be slow.

I think if there any solution that could control dashboard download and display rows limit would be perfect. For example, once query more than 500 rows, only display top 500 rows on the browser, and when download as csv can download full data set to the csv.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can optimise this.

1. **Database level optimisation:** Evaluate how long the query runs on your DB directly and compare it with superset. If there is not much of a difference then you need to look at optimising the query at the DB level. Ideally you want to push as much of the heavy lifting to the database.
2. **Superset level optimisation:**

   a) meta database: Move away from sqlite and migrate to mysql or
   postgres or the other supported DB's.

   b) Cache: Look at the [superset documentation](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/docs/installation/cache)

Comment: Cache not solve my problem, I just want to limit data rows when query return to the browser. But when I set limit parameter with 500 rows, it will set download dataset rows limit also.
So, I just want to set display rows limit, and not affect to the download datasets. 
For example, in one query with 5000 rows, just display top 500 rows, and download csv could download full datasets

Comment: Don't Set the limit in the query, instead turn the flag server pagination in the chart this will enable pagination on the server side and when you download the data it will download the entire result in CSV

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the optimisation in visualisation by turning the server pagination flag on in the chart builder page itself.